# C++ File Input/Output Console Output

Tags: c++, file, console

My question is how can I get my console to properly display the contents of fileB based on the below information.

Below is the code I have created for basic file input/output operations. I am trying to copy the content from fileA over to fileB. After this is done I am trying to display the contents of fileB to `cout`. The code runs and updates the contents of fileB to whatever was stored in fileA. However, the console does not display the new content of fileB. It just shows a blank box.

```
#include <iostream> // Read from files
#include <fstream>  // Read/Write to files
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

void perror();

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::ios; 


    using std::ifstream;
    ifstream ifile; // ifile = input file
    ifile.open("fileA.txt", ios::in);

    using std::ofstream;
    ofstream ofile("fileB.txt", ios::out); // ios::app adds new content to the end of a file instead of overwriting existing data.; // ofile = output file

    using std::fstream;
    fstream file; // file open fore read/write operations.

    if (!ifile.is_open()) //Checks to see if file stream did not opwn successfully. 
    {
        cout << "File not found."; //File not found. Print out a error message.
    }
    else
        {
        ofile << ifile.rdbuf(); //This is where the magic happens. Writes content of ifile to ofile.
        }

    using std::string; 
    string word; //Creating a string to display contents of files.

    // Open a file for read/write operations
    file.open("fileB.txt");

    // Viewing content of file in console. This is mainly for testing purposes. 
    while (file >> word)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }


    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
    file.close();
    getchar();
    return 0; //Nothing can be after return 0 in int main. Anything afterwards will not be run.
}
```

fileA.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

fileB.txt (file is initially a blank text document).

fileB.txt (after code runs)

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ofile` will have an internal buffer and if it isn't flushed and you only write a small amount of data (possibly as much as 64kb) then no data will be written to your output file until you call `ofile.close()` or at the end of `main()`.

Simply move `ofile.close()` to before `file.open("fileB.txt")`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Thanks for the explanation. It really helped me with the understanding of what what actually going on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't closed the oFile object before you open the FileB.

```
ofile.close();
file.open("fileB.txt");
```

By doing this you will have access to the updated file.